# Stop execution on button click - Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have 5 function calls in nested promise pattern. While the functions execute, I have a dialogue which shows loader and cancel button to cancel the execution. 
I can't upload my code here.

How to cancel or stop the execution of the functions on click of cancel button?

Comment: You dont have to upload your code but you should attempt the following... https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can structure your code in a way that allows you to control the flow of functions. You can use simple if statements for that.
In angular, you may also add an observer that will watch that particular button and then do the code that you want.